# Checking if new tab or window can be opened in javascript

Tags: javascript, inappbrowser

Is there a way to check if the current browser supports multiple tabs/windows. This is a common thing now because of in-app browsers.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to know if the browser supports the `window.open()` function?

Comment: What if we don't want to open a window yet and show different experiences based on that like say a message that says "This will open in a new tab" before they click.

Answer (score 1):

According to [mdn window.open docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), the `window.open()` call should return `null` if the call was unsuccessful.

> **Return value**
>
> A `WindowProxy` object, which is basically a thin wrapper for the `Window`
>   object representing the newly created window, and has all its features
>   available. ***If the window couldn't be opened, the returned value is
>   instead `null`.*** The returned reference can be used to access properties
>   and methods of the new window as long as it complies with Same-origin
>   policy security requirements.

As far as checking the ability to open a window without actually trying to open a window, there is no available API for that (as far as I know). You could open and close the window immediately again. Depending on the browser, the user may or may not see the brief flashing of a new window or tab.

```js
function window_open_check()
{
  w=window.open()
  if (w !== null){
    w.close()
    return true
  }
  return false
}

// Note:window.open() is blocked in StackOverflow scripts
console.log("window.open available:",window_open_check());
```

Comment: What if we don't want to open a window yet and show different experiences based on that like say a message that says "This will open in a new tab" before they click.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to check for ability without trying to open a window. You can close the window again immediately by w=window.open(); (if w!== null) w.close(),

Comment: I can accept that as answer if user does not notice anything.